# Vertically center text within input in Safari regardless of size

Tags: html, css, safari

I'm having an issue where Safari is adding more spacing at the top of a font than at the bottom in an input element. The problem is only visible when the font size of the input is almost as large or larger than the height of the input.

I'm looking for a solution that will work regardless of the font-size or height, so adding an arbitrary padding will not be acceptable.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Safari:

[image]

```css
input {
  font-size: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input value="0123">
```

Comment: The biggest concern is probably the fact that a different font family is being used in each browser. It'll be very difficult to ensure that it's centered in both browsers, consistently, unless you ensure the same font family is being used across the board. (as this extra space is generally caused by the positioning of characters in the font itself)

Comment: @BlakeMann Not true. This will happen even if the font is exactly the same on each browser.

Comment: @Cras to my knowledge, removing the browser auto-added margin/padding works. Could you accept my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tested my solution: adding css to remove browser padding/margin to the top of the stylesheet. This solution worked on the Windows version of Safari.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

input {
  font-size: 75px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input value="0123">
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0fkjxp8a/)

Hope this helps